# Ordered square is not path connected

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Could someone clarify the countability part in Munkres' proof that the ordered square is not path connected (Munkres Topology, Chapter 24, Example 6)

The proof proceeds as follows:

Let $p = 0 \times 0$ and $q = 1 \times 1$. Suppose there is a path $f: [a,b] \to I_o^2$ joining p and q.

By the intermediate value theorem, $f([a,b])$ must contain every point $x \times y$ of $I_o^2$. So, for each $x \in I$, define $U_x = f$$^-$$^1(x \times (0,1))$. The sets $U_x$ are non-empty, open in [a, b] by continuity of $f$, and disjoint.

Choose for each $x \in I$ a rational number $q_x \in U_x$. Thus since $U_x$ are disjoint, the map $x \mapsto q_x$ is an injective mapping of $I$ onto $\Bbb Q$ thus contradicting that the interval $I$ is uncountable.

My question is how $x \mapsto q_x$ can be injective if it's taking $x \in [0,1] \subset \Bbb R$ to $q_x \in (0,1) \subset \Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 2):

The map x to $q_x$ is injective beacause if $x\ne y$ then $U_x$ and $U_y$ are disjoint,   $q_x\in U_x$ and $q_y\in U_y$ so $q_x\ne q_y$

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing the definition of $ q_x $. Note that $ q_x $ is an element of the **preimage** of $ x \times (0,1) $ under $ f $, not an element of the interval $ x \times (0,1) $ itself.

The injectivity follows from the fact that each $ U_x $ is disjoint, so the map $ x \mapsto q_x \in U_x $ is indeed injective.

Comment: I see your correction, but my source of confusion remains. q(x) belonging to U(x) is an open subset of [a, b], the preimage of f. But the proof is still mapping x in [0,1] in the reals to an open interval in [a,b] in the rationals, and a choice functions is defined by recursion or induction which works on countable sets. At the heart of the Munkres proof here is that such choice function exists and is injective.

Comment: So, strictly speaking, a choice function is a function that allows you to choose an arbitrary point $ x \in I $. You get this from the axiom of choice. The mapping $ \varphi: x \mapsto q_x $ is then composed to the choice function (you can choose $ q_x $ in a similar fashion), which gives you existence. Injectivity still follows from the fact that each $ U_x $ is disjoint. The fact that $ I $ maps to an open interval doesn't matter; you can equally define $ \overline{\operatorname{Im}\varphi} \subset [a,b] $ to be a closed set into which $ \varphi $ maps.

Comment: I suppose the intuitive way to think of this proof is that, were $ I_o^2 $ path-connected, you should be able to find some open set in $ [a,b] $ that is the preimage of the interval $ ((x, 1), (x+\epsilon, 0)) $ under the path. In some sense, this open set is "too big" for arbitrarily small values of $ \epsilon $ to fit in $ [a,b] $ - this is where the contradiction that $ I $ is countable arises.

Comment: You don’t actually need the axiom of choice here: all you need is an enumeration $\Bbb Q=\{p_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ of the rationals, which can be constructed without $\mathsf{AC}$. Then for each $U_x$ you let $q_x$ be $p_n$ for the minimum $n$ such that $p_n\in U_x$.

Comment: I may be belaboring the point - but I can't see how the mapping can be injective. I get existence via enumeration of the rationals. Let $[a, b]$ in above be $[0, 1]$ so it's more obvious. Now $U_x \in [0, 1]$. For each real $x \in [0, 1]$ we are assigning a rational $q_x \in U_x \subset [0, 1]$. Now we're in [0, 1] for both $x$ and $U_x$ and we'd map every rational $x$ to rational $q_x$ and be left with no way to make the mapping injective, though existence is still guaranteed. Perhaps you can point me to some text on set theory that clarifies this. Thanks; sorry to keep beating on this.

Comment: I think the idea is that you have constructed a map that is formally injective, i.e., you've demonstrated it exists under the false assumption and that there is a way to define it such that it is injective. Clearly, though, it doesn't make sense for the map to be injective, for the reasons you've already pointed out. This doesn't affect the proof by contradiction. Another way to say this is that, if we assume $ I_o^2 $ is path-connected, we can define a mapping from a subset of the reals to a subset of the rationals. But this makes no sense, so $ I_o^2 $ cannot be path-connected.